# ng-repeat and render different HTML as per conditional statement

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So in angular we can do

```
<tag ng-repeat="item in items">content..</tag>
```

or

```
<tag ng-repeat-start="item in items"></tag><tag ng-repeat-end></tag>
```

I was wondering if there's a way to conditionally create the HTML, depending on the value of property on a javascript object. I know server side templating engines let mix code and HTML, so I was wondering if there's some way I could achieve something like the following.

```
contents of someview.html

<div ng-controller="someController as ctrl">

{{foreach(ctrl.items)

{{
    if (item.type == 'textbox')
    '<input type="text" value="item.value" />'
}}

{{
    if (item.type == 'checkbox')
    '<input type="checkbox" checked="item.value" />'
}}

end-foreach}}

</div>
```

I thought I would just use `ng-if` statement, but it doesn't cut it, since I don't want it to redundantly iterate over every object for each different element type and I also have a certain order I wish to preserve between the generated html elements, not simply generate all textbox elements first and then all checkbox etc. elements.

so

```
<input type="textbox" ng-if="item.type == 'textbox'" ng-repeat="item in items"/>

<input type="checkbox" ng-if="item.type == 'checkbox'" ng-repeat="item in items"/>
```

Won't cut it.

I am thinking I am going to have to use a directive and decorate an element with an attribute. Can the directive overwrite the element it's declared on with custom HTML ?

Comment: you will either have to iterate a `div` or `span` that holds the `ng-repeat`, or you will have to create a custom directive that conditionally replaces the template.  you can't perform this task inline with the `ng-repeat` and the `ng-if` defined on the same element.

Comment: @taguenizy the problem with that is that if there were textboxes and then checkboxes, the first would print all the textboxes, then the second would print all the checkboxes, not mixed in their original order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ng-repeat directive as an element. That way you could have the tags with the ngIf conditions as its content.

```
    <ng-repeat ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <tag ng-if="item.type == 'textbox'">   
            <input type="textbox">
        </tag>
        <tag ng-if="item.type == 'checkbox'">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </tag>            
    </ng-repeat>
```

Comment: It's very close to question proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) conditionally, a very clean way by my opinion:

```
<tag ng-repeat="item in item"><div ng-include="getTemplate(item)"></div></tag>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.getTemplate = function(item){
   if(item.type == 'textbox')
     return 'textboxTemplate.html';

   if(item.type == 'checkbox')
     return 'checkboxTemplate.html';

   //and so on...
}
```

Then, declare your scripts, either via the `<script>` tag or via the `$templateCache` service:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="checkboxTemplate.html">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value"/>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the "?" operator. something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
   <input type="(item.type == 'textbox') ? item.type : checkbox" checked="item.value" />
</div>
```